# Asyncio with memory leak (Python)

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.9

I have an issue with my (dockerized) application consuming an ever increasing amount of memory until the Linux kernel kills is. In the container's `docker logs` I only got an ominous `Killed` message without further context - only after checking the kernel logs (`cat /var/log/kern.log`) and `docker stats` did I realize what was happening - memory usage was going up by ~10MB per second.

The application is an asyncronous `grpc`-server with several concurrent tasks (using `return ensure_future(self._continuous_function)` to keep the function's task up and running, async so the server endpoints are not blocked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that `ensure_future()` caused my memory leak issue - or rather the `return` I used with it. Apparently the return meant that a reference to the original task was being kept in memory (instead of being garbage collected), and the function only had a very short wait time associated with it (1ms) - so memory kept building up fast.

So after removing the leak my app now consumes about 60MB of very constant memory. I hope this helps somebody else out, I couldn't find a reference to this exact issue which is why I'm sharing it here.

Comment: the code was essentially:
`task = asyncio.create_task(continuous_function())` and `await task` ... so `task` would save the reference which I guess kept building on itself

Comment: i know this is old.. but by any chance can you remember how you fixed it? think im having the same issue now. just remove the return part?

Comment: yes exactly, I didn't call the function over and over again - just a `while True` loop inside of it.

Comment: good advice. i also want to add that as soon as you add a asyncio.wait_for this totaly screws stuff as well. (incase anyone else is using a wait_for) im not totaly free of my leak yet but between not returning anything and cutting down on the awaits its definitely helped. 

also this works nicely following on wiseboar's answer:

"main"
`await asyncio.gather(*[task_1(),task_2())` and then task_1 and 2 are just the ```while true``` loops

Comment: This strategy helped me when using `ensure_future()`: https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/how-do-you-limit-memory-usage-with-asyncio.html

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a task in following way this way you can ensure that the task cleanup after itself.

````
import asyncio
from typing import Coroutine

from marie.helper import get_or_reuse_loop

background_tasks = set()


def run_background_task(coroutine: Coroutine) -> asyncio.Task:
    """Schedule a task reliably to the event loop.

    This API is used when you don't want to cache the reference of `asyncio.Task`.
    For example,

    ```
    get_event_loop().create_task(coroutine(*args))
    ```

    The above code doesn't guarantee to schedule the coroutine to the event loops

    When using create_task in a  "fire and forget" way, we should keep the references
    alive for the reliable execution. This API is used to fire and forget
    asynchronous execution.

    https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks
    """
    task = get_or_reuse_loop().create_task(coroutine)
    # Add task to the set. This creates a strong reference.
    background_tasks.add(task)

    # To prevent keeping references to finished tasks forever,
    # make each task remove its own reference from the set after
    # completion:
    task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)
    return task
````