# Asyncio + Aiohttp Memory Leak when running async function in for loop（more than 500000 requests) (python)

Tags: python, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am making lots of requests to get data from different urls.As my python program runs, my memory footprint grows, and after about ten minutes of running I can reach 8G of memory.I've seen a similar question[Asyncio + Aiohttp Memory Leak when running async function in for loop (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706394/asyncio-aiohttp-memory-leak-when-running-async-function-in-for-loop-python) but it doesn't work.My program works like this.(```is Omission of certain elements)

````
async def add_success_callback(future, callback):
    result = await future
    callback(result)

async def fetch(session,url):
    try:
        headers = {```}
        params = {```}
        jar = aiohttp.DummyCookieJar()
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=jar)
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, verify_ssl=False) as resp:
            return await resp.text(), await resp.read()

    except Exception:
        print(f"url: {url} error happened:")

async def fetch_all(urls):
    sem = Semaphore(100)
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            async with sem:
                task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url))         
                tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        datas = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        return datas

def get_result(data):
    text, content = data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.find('div', class_='name').text
    chupin = soup.find('div', class_="panel-wrapper", id="出品").text
    chupindict[name] = chupin



urls=[]
chupindict = {}
for i in range(0,500000):
      url = '```'
      urls.append(url)
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(urls))
loop.close()
````

It bothers me a lot but I'm a freshman and I've tried searching any information I can get.Any help will appreciated, thank you!

I've tried[Asyncio + Aiohttp Memory Leak when running async function in for loop (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706394/asyncio-aiohttp-memory-leak-when-running-async-function-in-for-loop-python)[https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/978][https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/978] but for the SSL solution I find that it works with httpx,I don't know whether can be used in my program.
I just want to solve the memory problem,thanks!

Comment: Is the double-up of ```task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url))``` in your actual code?

Comment: Roughly how big is the text in `chupin = soup.find('div', class_="panel-wrapper", id="出品").text` in size? Even 10KB would put you at 5GB of data with 500,000 requests. Have you tried to write the data to a file instead of storing everything in `chupindict` until the program ends?

Comment: @jwal sorry,it's my fault when editing it.I've corrected it.@Daviid Thanks for your suggestions,I'll try it.But Every time I get the text it's just a few words,I deem that it won't reach 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

With memory_profiler, I find that the memory problem exists in

```
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=jar)
async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, verify_ssl=False) as resp:
    return await resp.text(), await resp.read()
```

I don't close it correctly so the memory failed to be cleaned.After I fixed it

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=jar) as session:
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, verify_ssl=False) as resp:
        await session.close()
        return await resp.text(), await resp.read()
```

Thanks for every comments that help me solve the problem again!